# How to create “cell blocks” in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have an SQL query and I want to visually separate parts of it for readability. This is in the query code itself and will only be for my own reference. My current solution is to type a long string of ---------- as a comment and I'd like to know if there are any built-in methods to do this,
[similar to using %% in Matlab to insert a horizontal grey line](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015a/matlab/matlab_prog/cells_functions_fold.png).

Comment: can you show a screenshot?

Comment: There's already an image link showing what I'm trying to achieve. Note the horizontal grey line above each %% comment - that's what I want to insert. From the other response, it seems SQL doesn't have this feature and I may have to stick with my original method.

Comment: FYI, Microsoft refers to these as "regions" and support in their products varies widely. PowerShell ISE & Visual Studio support it, but SSMS does not. The ability to collapse & expand regions is called "code folding" (this term is generic, not specific to MS). SSMS will allow *some* sections of code to be folded, depending on syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure though but if you are trying to repeat the `-` character some x number of times then you can use [`REPLICATE ( string_expression ,integer_expression )`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx) function like below; which will repeat `-` character 20 times.

```
select replicate('-',20)
```

**EDIT:**

I think you are looking for a built-in text formatting property to include line. As far as my knowledge goes, there is no such built in design formatter present to include a horizontal grey line as line separator in `SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS)`

Comment: SQL Server 2012, as stated in the title.

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, there is no such built in design formatter present to include a horizontal grey line as line separator in `SQL Server Management Studio`

Comment: Alright then. It seems I may have to stick with my original method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a blocked comment, here is how I do it:

```
SELECT 
     /*************Comments Here*****************/
     t1.Field1
     t1.Field2
     t1.Field3

     /*************Comments Here*****************/
     t2.Field1
     t2.Field2
     t3.Field3

  FROM TABLE1 t1
  JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: I do something similar with -------- as stated in the question. From the other response, it seems I may have to stick with that method.

Comment: Yeah I would say, if you are just  trying to separate the data out, dashes work fine. But, if you are trying add some information to dashes then using a blocked  style comment is clean and better.